# call function only if extension exists

Tags: postgresql

I need use function `UNACCENT` to remove diacritic in `WHERE CLAUSE` but only if this extension is installed otherwise use normal string comparison.

Consider table A and B which can have hundred thousands of rows (history). Then I join from A to B and look for a specific string in B but not want check diacritics and obvious that must be fast almost same as a normal comparison (search in more fields must be too same speed)

```
CREATE EXTENSION unaccent;
--DROP EXTENSION unaccent;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS A;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS B;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE A (id serial, cost numeric, b_id int);
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE B (id serial, name varchar, surname varchar);

INSERT INTO B(id, name, surname) SELECT gen.id AS id, 'Some test name' || gen.id as name, 'Some test surname' || gen.id as surname FROM (SELECT generate_series(1,10000) as id) gen;
INSERT INTO A(id, cost, b_id) SELECT gen.id AS id, random() * 1000 as cost, (gen.id -1 ) / 10 + 1 FROM (SELECT generate_series(1,100000) as id) gen;

-- this cost 115 ms
SELECT * FROM A
LEFT OUTER JOIN B ON B.id = A.b_id
WHERE 
    B.name ILIKE '%e%' AND 
    B.surname ILIKE '%e%'

-- this cost 412 ms OR crash where not instaled extension
SELECT * FROM A
LEFT OUTER JOIN B ON B.id = A.b_id
WHERE 
    CASE WHEN (SELECT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM pg_extension WHERE extname = 'unaccent' AND extversion IS NOT NULL) LIMIT 1) THEN unaccent(B.name) ILIKE '%e%' ELSE B.name ILIKE '%e%' END AND 
    CASE WHEN (SELECT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM pg_extension WHERE extname = 'unaccent' AND extversion IS NOT NULL) LIMIT 1) THEN unaccent(B.surname) ILIKE '%e%' ELSE B.surname ILIKE '%e%' END
```

i need that second select be as same speed as first one and not to crash when extension is not instaled.

Thanks for help. Pavel

Comment: You will need dynamic SQL for this.

Comment: Core generates select from java, and can simply modify one where expression, but change whole request will be a lot refactoring. Best will be, if can modify only where row

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that in a single SQL statement, because a query is parsed before it is executed, and if `unaccent` does not exist, you would get a parsing error.

There are two possibilities:

1. Run two queries: the first one looks if the extension exists, and you construct the second query based on the outcome of the first.
2. You set a [`SAVEPOINT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-savepoint.html), then try the `unaccent` query, and if that fails, you `ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT` and try the other query.

   In PL/pgSQL, you would code that with a `BEGIN ... EXCEPTION ... END` block.